# Can I get a Func object for an Extension method

Tags: linq, extension-methods, ienumerable

I have a small utility extension method that performs some null checks on some LINQ extension methods in `IEnumerable<T>`.  The code looks like this

```
public static class MyIEnumerableExtensions
{
    // Generic wrapper to allow graceful handling of null values
    public static IEnumerable<T> NullableExtension<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>> f)
    {
        if (first == null && second == null) return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        if (first == null) return second;
        if (second == null) return first;
        return f(first, second);
    }

    // Wrap the Intersect extension method in our Nullable wrapper
    public static IEnumerable<T> NullableIntersect<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
    {
        // It'd be nice to write this as
        //
        //   return first.NullableExtension<T>(second, IEnumerable<T>.Intersect );
        //
        return first.NullableExtension<T>(second, (a,b) => a.Intersect(b));
    }
}
```

So, is there a way to pass in the `IEnumerable<T>.Intersect` extension method to `NullableExtension` directly rather than wrapping it in a lambda?

**Edit**

Because it is actually concise to pass in the `Enumerable` extension method, I removed the `NullableIntersect` (and other) methods and just call the nullable wrapper directly.

Also, as Anthony points out, the semantics of what an Empty enumerable should do is different depending on the extension method, i.e. `Union` versus `Intersect`.  As such, I rename the `NullableExtension` method to `IgnoreIfNull` which better reflects the generic behavior.

```
public static class MyIEnumerableExtensions
{
    // Generic wrappers to allow graceful handling of null values
    public static IEnumerable<T> IgnoreIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>> f)
    {
        if (first == null && second == null) return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        if (first == null) return second;
        if (second == null) return first;
        return f(first, second);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>> f)
    {
        return f(first ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>(), second ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>());
    }

}

// Usage example.  Returns { 1, 4 } because arguments to Union and Intersect are ignored
var items = new List<int> { 1, 4 };
var output1 = items.IgnoreIfNull(null, Enumerable.Union).IgnoreIfNull(null, Enumerable.Intersect);

// Usage example.  Returns { } because arguments to Union and Intersect are set to empty
var output2 = items.EmptyIfNull(null, Enumerable.Union).EmptyIfNull(null, Enumerable.Intersect);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Intersect` is defined within static class `Enumerable`. You can pass it into your method like below

```
return first.NullableExtension<T>(second, Enumerable.Intersect);
```

Note: You *might* be concerned about the behavior of your logic in the case of a null sequence. For example, in the case of

```
List<int> first = null;
var second = new List<int> { 1, 4 };
var output = first.NullableIntersect(second).ToList();
```

You have defined it such that `output` contains `{1, 4}` (the elements of `second`). I might expect `first` to instead be treated as an empty sequence, and an intersection with `second` would result in an empty sequence. Ultimately, that's for you to decide the behavior you desire.

Comment: Just tracked this down myself.  +1 to you for speed.

Comment: @Lucas, I had one concern I just added, be sure to check the revision to see if it is a stumbling block.

Comment: Yes, I did notice this and renamed the extension method to `IgnoreIfNull` in my project to better reflect the semantics, i.e. `var output = first.IgnoreIfNull(second, Enumerable.Intersect)`